# SVG file doesn't show up in blender

Tags: svg

[image]
[image]

I made a vector image in Adobe Illustrator and exported it into a svg file.(I did my best to make the lines closed but please still check if there's any problem with the vector image.)
But when I import it in blender, nothing comes out. I also zoomed in but there was absolutely nothing on the editor. Neither scale didn't work. Weird thing is I can still see the list of curves of svg file in outliner.

I've even tried with simple circle shape but the result was same. Please give a help.

Comment: The object looks very small, try to zoom in or scale the object.

Comment: .. further to comment above, the curve dimensions are less than 0.0004 x 0.0004 x 0  .To make this the size of a 2 x 2 plane will need to scale by fifty thousand (50, 000)

Answer (score 4):

Replicating your steps:

I vectorized your design and I saved it in SVG.

Imported in Blender and I noticed the svg comes too small.

Not so small as yours.

I entered Edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then Select all <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>50</kbd> and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This made it big enough.

In your case, I think <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>200</kbd> could be enough.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: sorry for the late comment. I followed your explanation and it worked. Thank you so much for your help!