# Simple SVG from Illustrator or Inkscape fails to show

Tags: svg

I just installed Blender with `brew cask install blender`. I tried to import an SVG with File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphics and it did not show. I made a simple SVG file with a circle in both Illustrator and Inkscape and I don't see it in the window. I zoomed out and still could not find it. Here is my screen:

[image: Blender screen without SVG file]

I read [this answer on raster graphics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/imported-svg-files-does-not-show-up) and [this answer on Illustrator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape). I confirm that I don't have raster graphics and that I exported the Illustrator files with those directions.

Here are dropbox links to the SVG files created: Illustrator circle, Inkscape circle (604B and 2kB respectively).

After importing, the Outliner adds a `Curve` item:

[image: View of outliner after import]

Clicking the eye of this item to show or hide makes no difference in the viewport.

I am new to Blender. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

*Update*: I removed the Drobpox links because the question already has a solution, and one can easily redo them with Illustrator or Inkscape.

Comment: Where are the dropbox links? Also, a screenshot of the Outliner in Blender would be quite useful to see, if there was anything imported at all.

Comment: the imported svg is often very very small, maybe it's the case here? As Metaphor said, if the svg is here you should see it in the Outliner panel. Try to select the centre with the lasso tool (ctrl) then scale up a lot. If the svg is not here, there's an import problem.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44520/why-are-my-svg-imports-so-small

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116366/svg-file-doesnt-show-up-in-blender?r=SearchResults

Comment: Possible duplicar of [why can't I import a svg file from illustrator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape/23171#23171)

Comment: @metaphor-set Sorry, my Dropbox app added `file://var...` links and I updated them to the Dropbox links. I also added a screenshot of the Outliner.

Comment: @moonboots You were right, the SVG was very small and I could find it with the lasso tool.